# What does the <> symbol mean in InterpolatingFunction?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, symbols

What does `<>` (less than followed by greater than) mean in Mathematica? For example:

```
InterpolatingFunction[{-6,6},{0,6}],<>[x,y]
```

I am very much confused in such kind of expressions. As I have received such kind of output in `NDSolve`.

Comment: @JakeGould That question is for a different environment (SQL) and any assumptions made between the two are unfounded without further justification.

Comment: (Make sure that's the correct/full output, the brackets look unbalanced.)

Comment: [InterpolatingFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html): "In standard output format, only the domain element of an InterpolatingFunction object is printed explicitly. The remaining elements are indicated by <>" (I have no idea what it means though)

Comment: Mathematica tries to abbreviate some of the things it puts up. It does this for InterpolatingFunction, it does this for Graph ( not the plot of a function, but a set of points and connecting edges ) and it does this for some other things. It does this trying to hide what it thinks is a lot of distracting detail that isn't important to you. If you evaluate FullForm[Interpolation[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}, {5, 2}}]] it will show you the likely uninteresting detail that it is hiding when it thinks all you really want to do is USE the interpolating function, not see inner data.

Comment: thanks all for the help and correction. It helped to removed ambiguities about this symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematica expressions come with a [head](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Head.html) and then several arguments. For example, the output of some operation might give you the output List[1,2,3,4,5]. However, Mathematica knows this is a list and the output is formatted as {1,2,3,4,5} instead.

A function like `Interpolation` will give you a special type of object (an interpolating function) that has many components. Unlike list, most of its components are irrelevant, so you can ignore them. Mathematica hides them using `<>` so that you don't have to look at them.

```
f = Interpolation[RandomInteger[10, 10]]
output: InterpolatingFunction[{{1, 10}}, "<>"]
```

All it shows you is the Head, which is `InterpolatingFunction`, and then the first argument which is the domain(s) of the function. There is only one variable, so there is only one domain `{1,10}` so the list of domains is `{{1,10}}`.

All the other arguments are there, so you can find them. You can evaluate f by:

```
f[2.3]
output: 0.7385
```

(Your output will vary!) But you can also look at the pieces of f:

```
f[[2]]
output: {4, 3, 0, {10}, {4}, 0, 0, 0, 0, Automatic}
```

The second piece, normally hidden, is a list of different properties of the interpolating function that we normally don't care about.

You can change the head on many things using `@@` which changes the header of one thing into another. For example:

```
mylist = {2,3,4,5};
Plus@@mylist
output: 14
```

You can do this with our function:

```
List@@f
output: {{{1, 10}}, {4, 3, 0, {10}, {4}, 0, 0, 0, 0, Automatic},
         {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}, {{9}, {2}, {0}, {6},
          {10}, {6}, {7}, {5}, {0}, {6}}, {Automatic}}
```

All of that is the "guts" of the interpolating function. That's what's missing in the `<>`, because this might describe the interpolating function but we don't really need to see it.

If you are looking for an explicit polynomial interpolation, you should be doing:

```
InterpolatingPolynomial[RandomInteger[10, 10], x]
```

which gives you a function of x (in a very non-simplified form) that is what you want.

Comment: very detailed description. Thank you very much.